# firestore read data adding hashmap get data when added

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

[image]

when the user presses the button onlick ,read data and add hashmap
When completed I want to read with getfirestore2() method

data to come
comment1
comment2
comment3
comment4

but incoming data with getfirestore2() method
comment 4

my using method failed and not safe because I use delay

I how to fix codes?

my codes

```
    binding.AllAskedBtn.setOnClickListener {
        a1hliste.clear()
        a2hliste.clear()
        a3hliste.clear()
        a4hliste.clear()

         fun getfirestore2(){
            println("listedekiler A1 "+a1hliste)
            println("listedekiler A2 "+a2hliste)
            println("listedekiler A3 "+a3hliste)
            println("listedekiler A4 "+a4hliste)
            println("\n veri 2 db size "+dbsize)
             var sayi=0


             var g1=a1hliste.getValue(sayi).toString()
             var g2=a2hliste.getValue(sayi).toString()
             var g3=a3hliste.getValue(sayi).toString()
             var g4=a4hliste.getValue(sayi).toString()

                for (a in 0..dbsize-1){
                    db.collection(g1).document(g2).collection(g3).document(g4).addSnapshotListener { task,e->
                        var veri= task!!.get("comment") as String
                        println("This is the data from "+veri)
                    }
                }

                }


       db.collection("users").document(uuid).collection("Questions").orderBy("date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener{ result, e->
           var veri=result!!.documents
           var verisize=result!!.documents.size
           dbsize=0
           for (a in veri){
               var dersler=a.get("FBDersler") as String
               var konular=a.get("FBKonular") as String
               var sinavturu=a.get("sinavturu") as String
               var QuestionUİD=a.get("QuestionUİD") as String


               a1hliste.put(dbsize,sinavturu.toString())
               a2hliste.put(dbsize,dersler.toString())
               a3hliste.put(dbsize,konular.toString())
               a4hliste.put(dbsize,QuestionUİD.toString())
               dbsize+=1

               GlobalScope.launch {
                   delay(2000L)
                   if (dbsize==verisize){
                       getfirestore2()
                   }
               }
           }
           println("db size "+dbsize)
       }





    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: haven't anything error in code is working, my promlem firestore. 
I am listening with addSnapshotListener  and when it arrives ı am adding hasmap and start other addSnapshotListener  but its here only one  document here ,there should be more

Comment: I mean nested document read with hashmap

Comment: I'm sorry but I have a hard time understanding what you need.

Comment: look my image 1 ,there users/uuid/questions/uuid=> I am listening this collections in document I getting this field: sınavturu,Fbdersler,Fbkonular,QueationUİD And ve ı am all document value save with hashmap and if all data comes. I call this functions getquestion2() İn there is a addsnapshotlistener method have With this method, I'm pulling the data I received earlier. Example db.sinavturu.FBdersler.FBkonular.Questionuud I want to comment fields in ,there 4 comment have but I getting one comment field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finding solution
nested firestore listeners for , I am using .addOnSuccessListener  method

```
  binding.AllAskedBtn.setOnClickListener {
            a1hliste.clear()
            a2hliste.clear()
            a3hliste.clear()
            a4hliste.clear()
            db.collection("users").document(uuid).collection("Questions").orderBy("date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener{ task->
                var a=0
                for (documents in task){
                    var dersler:String?=null
                    var konular:String?=null
                    var sinavturuu:String?=null
                    var QuestionUİD:String?=null

                    sinavturuu=documents["sinavturu"] as String
                    dersler=documents["FBDersler"] as String
                    konular=documents["FBKonular"] as String
                    QuestionUİD=documents["QuestionUİD"] as String

                    println(QuestionUİD.toString())

                    a1hliste.put(a,sinavturuu.toString())
                    a2hliste.put(a,dersler.toString())
                    a3hliste.put(a,konular.toString())
                    a4hliste.put(a,QuestionUİD.toString())
                    a+=1
                }
            }.addOnSuccessListener {
                var Anumber=0
                for (b in 0..a4hliste.size-1){
                    var g1=a1hliste.getValue(b).toString()
                    var g2=a2hliste.getValue(b).toString()
                    var g3=a3hliste.getValue(b).toString()
                    var g4=a4hliste.getValue(b).toString()
                        db.collection(g1).document(g2).collection(g3).document(g4).addSnapshotListener { value,e->
                            val Aphotourl=value!!.get("questionphotourl") as String
                            val Asinavtürü=value!!.get("sinavturu") as String
                            val Akonular=value!!.get("FBKonular") as String
                            val Adersler=value!!.get("FBDersler") as String
                            val Adocid=value!!.get("QuestionUİD") as String
                            val AFBusername=value!!.get("username") as String
                            val Aanswercheck=value!!.get("answercheck") as Boolean

                            Anumber+=1

                            usernamelist.add(AFBusername)
                            ProfileSınavTürü.put(Anumber,Asinavtürü)
                            ProfileFBDersler.put(Anumber,Adersler)
                            ProfileKonular.put(Anumber,Akonular)

                            ProfileQuestionUİD.put(Anumber,Adocid)
                            photoUrlList.put(Anumber,Aphotourl)
                            answercheckmap.put(Anumber,Aanswercheck)

                            adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```